# Controlled Iteration through bash array using nested for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, yq

common.yml file

```
tomcat9_version:               "9.0.64-154"
openjdk11_version:                "11.54.24-95"
newrelic_infra_agent_version:  "0.1.22-42"
```

vars.yml

```
Tomcat:
  packages:
    OpenJDK11:
      - 11.52.24
    Tomcat9:
      - 9.0.50
   newrelic_infra:
      - 0.1.21
```

Capture values of tomcat9_version, openjdk11_version, newrelic_infra_agent_version from common.yml and replace OpenJDK11, Tomcat9, newrelic_infra values in vars.yml

What i wrote

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=("openjdk11_version" "tomcat9_version" "newrelic_infra_agent_version")
declare -a brr=("OpenJDK11:" "Tomcat9:" "newrelic_infra:")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   value=$(grep "$i" common.yaml  | awk '{print $NF}')
   echo "$value"
    for i in "${brr[@]}"
    do
      pakru=$(awk -v var=$i '$1 == "-"{ if (key == var) print $NF;next } {key=$1}' vars.yaml)
      echo "$pakru"
      sed -i "s/$pakru/$value/g" "vars.yaml"
      break
   done
done
```

The output i got

```
"11.54.24-95"
11.52.24
9.0.50
0.1.21
"9.0.64-154"
11.52.24
9.0.50
0.1.21
"0.1.22-42"
11.52.24
9.0.50
0.1.21
```

expected output:-

```
"11.54.24-95"
11.52.24
"9.0.64-154"
9.0.50
"0.1.22-42"
0.1.21
```

Comment: I don't see how you get this output from this script. Of course you won't get the expected output either. The inner loop has an unconditional `break` at the end, which means that it is terminated after the first iteration and never actually loops. Another problem is that outer and inner loop use the same variable `i` for looping. If you debug your program with `set -x` turned on, those errors will be immediately obvious to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a specialized tool like `yq` can help handling YAML with the shell:

```sh
yq eval-all '
    select(fi == 0) as $common |
    select(fi == 1) |                                
    .Tomcat.packages.OpenJDK11[0] = $common.openjdk11_version |
    .Tomcat.packages.Tomcat9[0] = $common.tomcat9_version |
    .Tomcat.packages.newrelic_infra[0] = $common.newrelic_infra_agent_version
' common.yml vars.yml
```

```yaml
Tomcat:
  packages:
    OpenJDK11:
      - "11.54.24-95"
    Tomcat9:
      - "9.0.64-154"
    newrelic_infra:
      - "0.1.22-42"
```

Comment: If common.yml changed to :-

` profile::test::profile_tomcat::test_tomcat9_version:               "9.0.62-154"
  profile::test::profile_java::test_openjdk11_version:                "11.54.24-95"
  profile::test::profile_systemlogging::test_newrelic_infra_agent_version:  "0.1.22-42" `

How can get the same output as above

Comment: that would be for example `.Tomcat.packages.Tomcat9[0] = $common.[0]."profile::test::profile_tomcat::test_tomcat9_version"`

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

yq eval-all ' select(fi == 0) as $common | select(fi == 1) | .Tomcat.packages.OpenJDK11[0] = $common.openjdk11_version | .Tomcat.packages.Tomcat9[0] = $common.tomcat9_version |.Tomcat.packages.newrelic_infra[0] = $common.newrelic_infra_agent_version ' common.yml vars.yml `


Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:9 failing at 1:12.
        unmatched text: "fi "

getting the this  error  while running

Comment: Common.yml file 
`profile::test::profile_tomcat::test_tomcat9_version:               "9.0.64-154"`



`yq eval $common.[0]."profile::test::profile_tomcat::test_tomcat9_version" common.yml`

getting error

Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:15 failing at 1:17.
        unmatched text: "te"

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=("openjdk11_version" "tomcat9_version" "newrelic_infra_agent_version")
declare -a brr=("OpenJDK11:" "Tomcat9:" "newrelic_infra:")
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++))
do
   value=$(egrep "${arr[$i]}" common.yaml  | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq | cut -d '-' -f1 | tr -d '"')
   echo "$value"
   pakru=$(awk -v var=${brr[$i]} '$1 == "-"{ if (key == var) print $NF;next } {key=$1}' vars.yaml)
   echo "$pakru"
   sed -i "s/$pakru/$value/g" "vars.yaml"
done
```